# If for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$, such that for any $|x-x_0| < \delta,~ (L-\epsilon)^k \leq f(x) \leq (L+\epsilon)^k,$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Claim: If for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$, such that for any $|x-x_0| < \delta$, it holds $(L-\epsilon)^k \leq f(x) \leq (L+\epsilon)^k,$
where $k$ and $L$ are positive constants.

Then we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) =L^k.$

The following is my proof.

Since $\lim_{\xi \rightarrow 0} (L+ \xi)^k = L^k,$ for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta' >0$, such that for any $0 < \xi < \delta'$, it holds
$(L+\xi)^k - L^k < \epsilon.$

Then for $\delta'/2>0$, there exists $\delta >0$, such that when $|x-x_0| < \delta$, it holds $ f(x) \leq (L+ \delta'/2)^k,$ and therefore, $f(x) - L^k \leq (L+ \delta'/2)^k - L^k < \epsilon.$.

The other direction can use the same method.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You should have $f(x) \to L^k$.

Comment: Why go through the trouble with $\delta' / 2$? $(L + \xi)^k - L^k \leq \epsilon \Rightarrow f(x) - L^k \leq (L + \xi)^k - L^k < \epsilon$ is enough. Otherwise this looks fine (provided that you meant to type $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L^k$ in the claim).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah, I have changed it. Thank you for pointing out that.

Comment: Should the first inequality for $f(x_0)$?

however, note that $|a+b|^k \leq 2^{k-1} (|a|^k + |b|^k$. 

Then

$|(L+\epsilon)^k - (L-\epsilon)^k| \leq |(L+\epsilon)^k - L^k \leq |2^{k-1} (L^k + \epsilon^k) -L^k| \leq |2^{k-1} (L^k + \epsilon^k) -2^{k-1}L^k|< 2^{k-1}\epsilon$

Comment: Can't you instead just let $\epsilon\to 0^+$ and quote the squeeze theorem?